# Python code to subtract column of a line with previous line column from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file "input.txt" which contains 6 columns

```
520743  ID:1     407585 16630998 70843 174935
540743  ID:1     418010 17275747 70843 179499
560744  ID:1     429340 17919579 70905 183799
580744  ID:1     439450 18564636 70905 188148
20595   ID:2     29487 625836 11282 10382
40596   ID:2     45984 1264642 14266 20974
21258   ID:3     46215 609159 20895 16586
41259   ID:3     63166 1247485 24201 24052
61257   ID:3     72732 1893258 24201 28660
```

I want to subtract from each column value the previous line column value if tge `ID` is the same. For example `Line2_cloumn3 - line1_column3: 418010 - 407585 = 10425` and write to another file like this:

```
20000 ID:1 10425 644749 0 4564
```

How can I do that in python?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('input.txt') as inf, open('out.txt', 'w') as outf:
prev = next(inf)
string = prev.split()[1]   
abc=int(string.split(":",1)[1])   
for line in inf:
  string = prev.split()[1]   
  abc=int(string.split(":",1)[1])  
  cstring = line.split()[1]   
  cabc=int(cstring.split(":",1)[1])     
  if abc==cabc:
      value=[]
      pval1=int(prev.split()[2])
      cval1=int(line.split()[2])
      val1=cval1-pval1
      value.append(val1)         
      pval2=int(prev.split()[3])
      cval2=int(line.split()[3])
      val2=cval2-pval2
      value.append(val2)          
      pval3=int(prev.split()[4])
      cval3=int(line.split()[4])
      val3=cval3-pval3         
      value.append(val3)
      pval4=int(prev.split()[5])
      cval4=int(line.split()[5])
      val4=cval4-pval4
      value.append(val4)          
  prev=line
```

I have written this code, it works. How can I improve this?